# How can an interface method be called directly?

Tags: c#

I'm reading some code, can you please explain what the below line does?

```
bool isFeatureEnabled = FeatureControl.Current.Features.AppDesigner.IsEnabled(organizationId,currentOrgDBVersion);
```

Here's the definitions of the above code

```
public sealed class FeatureControl : IFeatureControl
{
    public static IFeatureControl Current { get; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IFeatureDetailContainer Features { get; set; }
    ....
}


public interface IFeatureControl
{
    IFeatureDetailContainer Features { get; set; }
    ...
}


public interface IFeatureDetailContainer
{
    IFeatureDetail AppDesigner { get; }
}

public interface IFeatureDetail
{
    bool IsEnabled(Guid organizationId, Version currentOrgDBVersion);
}
```

I don't see any instances created, how does this work?

Sorry, I copied metadata, I just found the actual code:

```
public sealed class FeatureControl : IFeatureControl
{

    private static readonly Lazy<IFeatureControl> current = new Lazy<IFeatureControl>(() => new FeatureControl());
    private IFeatureDetailContainer features;
    public static IFeatureControl Current
        {
            get
            {
                return current.Value;
            }
        }

    /// <summary>
        /// Accessor to the Features List for Developers to retrieve the information
        /// </summary>
        [XmlIgnore]
        public IFeatureDetailContainer Features
        {
            get
            {
                return this.features;
            }
            set
            {
                this.features = value;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How do we know the instance is not created in the code you have omitted ?

Comment: `Current` is marked as `static` in `FeatureControl.Current`. So the instance can be created and assigned at any part of your other code.

Comment: Maybe you can check **call stack**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a singleton pattern. Normally, the instance is created inside constructor.

```
public interface IFeatureControl { }
public sealed class FeatureControl : IFeatureControl
{
    public static IFeatureControl Current { get; }

    static FeatureControl()
    {
        if (Current == null)
        {
            Current = new FeatureControl();
        }
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class FeatureControlTests
{
    [Test]
    public void IsFeatureControlSingleton()
    {
        IFeatureControl c1 = FeatureControl.Current;
        IFeatureControl c2 = FeatureControl.Current;
        Assert.AreSame(c1, c2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the code (not shown here) you can expect the object **IFeatureControl::Current** is being created / new'd.

Your line of code is merely accessing that value.  Note that if you run the code without actually instantiating the **Current** object you'll get a null ref. error.

You can program an elaborate set of code using Interfaces and the code will compile and look great, however if none of the interface objects are instantiated with new'd instances of classes that inherit from the Interface you'll get null reference exceptions.

Consider the use of interfaces in this example an outline for how things WILL be arranged and how they WILL operate.  However it's just an outline and you'll need to colour inside the lines to actually achieve an outcome.
Good luck!